# How to keep paragraphs intact and not converted to line breaks when text pasting from Word in Wygwam

Tags: wygwam, wysiwyg

How can I keep paragraphs intact and not converted to line breaks when text pasted from Word in Wygwam?

I am copying and pasting from Word in Wygwam. The text in Word has paragraphs but when pasted into Wygwam field it's converted to line breaks (br tags).

Is there a setting or configuration to allow me keep the return carriages?

Thanks

Comment: Does the "Paste as Plain Text" button do what you're looking for?

Comment: As mentioned in the accepted answer below, I need to paste using the Paste From Word button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add the icon Paste From Word into your WYGWAM settings it looks like this:[image]

That'll keep basic formatting intact for you. Paste from plain text doesn't keep basic formatting. Paste from Word is handy when you are pasting content from other websites thave inline styles implemented as it removes all of that too!